# how range the main screen's icons when switch between two languages?

Tags: android, icons, main-activity

I tried to arrange my icons in main screen in English version & it's ok, but when switch the language to Arabic Version, main screen works with unsuitable arrangement each icon in place far of another..

How I can solve this problem ??

[image: English version screen]

[image: Arabic version screen]

this is a whole main screen  XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pic2"
android:gravity="clip_vertical|clip_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/courses"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/academic_text "
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/contacts_text "
        android:background="@drawable/courses" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contacts_text "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contacts"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:text="@string/contacts"
        android:textColor="@color/lomon_chiffon"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ouwebsite"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/aouwebsite"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/aouwebsite"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aouwebsite"
        android:background="@drawable/ou_website1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/courses_text "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/courses"
        android:layout_below="@+id/courses"
        android:text="@string/courses"
        android:textColor="@color/lomon_chiffon"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aouwebsite"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/facebook"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebook"
        android:background="@drawable/aou_website99" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twitter"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/about"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/about"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/courses_text "
    android:background="@drawable/contacts" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_text "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/about"
    android:layout_below="@+id/about"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:text="@string/about"
    android:textColor="@color/lomon_chiffon"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_text "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/about"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/student"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:text="@string/news"
    android:textColor="@color/lomon_chiffon"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/academic_text "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/academic_calendar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/academic_calendar"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:text="@string/academic_calendar"
    android:textColor="@color/lomon_chiffon"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/academic_text "
    android:layout_below="@+id/academic_text "
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/about1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/twitter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/academic_calendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/news"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/news_text "
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/news_text "
    android:background="@drawable/news1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/student"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/student_text "
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contacts_text "
    android:background="@drawable/email" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_text "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contacts"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contacts_text "
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:text="@string/student_email"
    android:textColor="@color/lomon_chiffon"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: Sreenshot of your problem will help us **a lot**

Comment: this is XML code for RelativeLayout type of main screen layout: 
`<RelativeLayout 
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" > `

Comment: I can't add picture because I'm new in website

Comment: You should be editing your question and put the source codes there. If you can't upload images here, you may consider uploading them elsewhere and provide links to them here...

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo Android xml. This would get you three icons that are equally spaced across the screen. The language won't matter because the text will just go onto two lines if it happens to take up more than 33% of the screen.

Just use two of these in your relative layout:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:orientation = "horizontal" >

  <TextView
     android:layout_width = "0dip"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:drawableTop = "@drawable/news"
     android:text = "@string/news" 
     android:layout_weight = "33" />

  <TextView
     android:layout_width = "0dip"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:drawableTop = "@drawable/course"
     android:text = "Courses" 
     android:layout_weight = "33" />

  <TextView
     android:layout_width = "0dip"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:drawableTop = "@drawable/calendar"
     android:text = "Calendar" 
     android:layout_weight = "33" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(just haven't got time to do it all for you :p )

Comment: but it is a button not drawable ??

Comment: at the end of the day Button extends TextView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop